# How to countdown till a future day in an android application?

Tags: android, countdown, days

I want to add to my application a new future, which shows, in a textView, the days left till a specific day, day setted by me, and the textView to be changed after every day passes. I tried a lot of things, a serched more than a lot, but nothing so far.

**I started from here:**

```
CountDownTimer countDown = new CountDownTimer(3000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    countDown.start();
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Did you try a runnable and set the amount of time you want to wait?

Comment: I just don't know how to show the days number, I could only show the date till the countdown will have to count. There is the problem, how to show the number of days?

Comment: is there a user opens application for a whole day!!! :\

Comment: He is asking if there is possibly a user who will have your app open whole day long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did something similar a long time ago for a widget so just check out the code below and let me know if there's anything unclear. It might not be 100% "proper" since it was at the time when I was starting to code for Android but it should give you an idea...

```
    private static final long MILLIS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    private static final long MILLIS_IN_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    // ...


    Time awaitedTime = new Time();
    awaitedTime.set(second, minute, hour, day, month, year);

    Time defaultTime = new Time();
    defaultTime.set(0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 1989);

    if (awaitedTime.toMillis(false) == defaultTime.toMillis(false)) {

        return "No date";
    }
    else {

        int tempRest = 0;

        Time currentTime = new Time();
        currentTime.setToNow();

        long remainingTime = awaitedTime.toMillis(false) - currentTime.toMillis(false);
        int remainingDays = (int) (remainingTime / MILLIS_IN_DAY);

        tempRest = (int) (remainingTime % MILLIS_IN_DAY);
        int remainingHours = (int) (tempRest / MILLIS_IN_HOUR);

        // return YOUR STRING HERE
    }
```

Comment: What is not so unclear: defaultTime.set(0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 1989); - reffers to the present time? How should it be setted for this days if I'm right? , and then, how to set how many days should it count? Thanks !

Comment: That `defaultTime` thing is just something for me to check if the time I'd downloaded from the Internet is actually existing etc.
As for the rest, take a look at the last lines - it's right there. Basically, you convert the current time and the awaited time to milliseconds and see by how much they differ. Then, divide the difference in milliseconds by the amount of milliseconds in 24 hours to get the time you want.

Btw: "to set" is an irregular verb and its past tense is "set" as well (i.e. not "setted") :)

Comment: I can't get your idea about converting the time. Can't you, please, edit you post and give me an example for 77 days left? Thanks !

Comment: Time timeCurrent = new Time();
  timeCurrent.setToNow();
  
  Time timeAwaited = new Time();
  timeAwaited.set(77 * MILLIS_IN_DAY);
  
  long millisNow = timeCurrent.toMillis(false);
  long millisYour = timeAwaited.toMillis(false);

I'm afraid I can't make it any simpler than that. Not sure what the time is where you are right now but this is rather simple - if I were you I'd spend some time trying to figure it out; if it's night perhaps try to give it a go in the morning...

Comment: But what method your using to make it work and where should I put my textView id?

Comment: Well, you can write something similar to what's I've provided and make it return type String and write something like `return String.valueOf(remainingDays);` and once you've got that, just use this method to feed the String into your textView :)

Comment: A lot of new information. I'll give it a try soon. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't know how to show the days number, I could only show the
>   date till the countdown will have to count. There is the problem, how
>   to show the number of days?

I suggest you to use [JodaTime](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/).

```
Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(start), new LocalDate(end)).getDays()
```

About update:

Wy don't you just update the remaining days in onResume(). Do you really want to cover that case, when the user uses you app midnight?:)

If that is the case, you can use AlarmManager. Here is a draft:

```
AlarmManager manager = Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, UpdateDaysReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

manager.setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, 24*60*60*1000, pi)
```

You can handle the update in the UpdateDaysReceiver.